# Creating a stub of document.getSelection using Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, sinon

My function, which you can find below, uses `document.getSelection`to get the currently selected text on the screen. I need to be able to specify the value of `document.getSelection` so that I test my function.

I tried creating the stub like so:

```
document.getSelection = sinon.stub(document, "getSelection", function() { return "Hello world!" } );

var selection = wysiwyg.getCurrentRange();
```

However, It just get `undefined` for selection. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the method I'm testing:

```
 Wysiwyg.prototype.getCurrentRange = function() {
    var sel, range;
    if ( window.getSelection ) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if ( sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount ) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt( 0 );
        }
    } else if ( document.selection ) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
    }

    return range;
 };
```

Comment: Is the issue solved now?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, can you award the bounty as well? I am the only who provided an answer. As you confirmed it was useful.

Comment: Sorry, bounty didnt show up in the SO app so I assumed it was automatically awarded. You should have received it now.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 errors in your code:

1. The first one is obvious. If you like to create a stub for
   `window.getSelection` you should apply it to `window.getSelection`
   (not `document.getSelection`).
2. The second one is obvious too.
   Originally `sel` and `range` are `undefined`. You substitute
   `document.getSelection` with a function that returns the string
   'Hello world!' (see the line #4). Hence `sel` becomes equal to
   'Hello world!' and `sel.getRangeAt` together with `sel.rangeCount`
   are `undefined`. Hence the whole expression `sel.getRangeAt &&
   sel.rangeCount` is `false` and `range` that you return as the result
   remains `undefined` (the exact result that you got).
3. You should assign the result of `sinon.stub` to
   a new variable (not to the substituted method).
4. Always restore the original method in the end of the test.

Please, also note that you cannot apply a stub to a method if the method is not defined.

Taking into account everything from the above in your case a solution without stubs is better.

To test the positive branch you can use

```
var getRangeAtResult = 'getRangeAt Expected Result';
var getRangeAtSpy = sinon.spy(function() {
    return getRangeAtResult;
});

var windowGetSelectionBackUp = window.getSelection;
window.getSelection = function() {
    return {
        getRangeAt: getRangeAtSpy,
        rangeCount: true
    };
};

wysiwyg.getCurrentRange().should.be.equal(getRangeAtResult);

getRangeAtSpy.withArgs(0).called.should.be.equal(true);
window.getSelection = windowGetSelectionBackUp;
```

If you are sure that `document.getSelection` is defined you can use stub

```
var getRangeAtResult = 'getRangeAt Expected Result';
var getRangeAtSpy = sinon.spy(function() {
    return getRangeAtResult;
});

var documentGetSelectionStub = sinon.stub(document, 'getSelection', function() {
    return {
        getRangeAt: getRangeAtSpy,
        rangeCount: true
    };
});

wysiwyg.getCurrentRange().should.be.equal(getRangeAtResult);

getRangeAtSpy.withArgs(0).called.should.be.equal(true);
documentGetSelectionStub.restore();
```

To test the negative branch you can use

```
var createRangeResult = 'createRange Expected Result';
var createRangeSpy = sinon.spy(function() {
    return createRangeResult;
});

var documentSelectionBackUp = document.selection;
document.selection = function() {
    return {createRange: createRangeSpy};
};

wysiwyg.getCurrentRange().should.be.equal(createRangeResult);

createRangeSpy.called.should.be.equal(true);
document.selection = documentSelectionBackUp;
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. At the beginning of your answer you corrected me by stating that I should be spying on `window.getSelection()` but then part of the way through your answer you switched and said "If you are sure that `document.getSelection` is defined you can use stub". So which one should I be spying on `document.getSelection()` or `window.getSelection()` ?

Comment: Please, recheck your code. `document.getSelection` is used nowhere. Don't you see it? You use `window.getSelection` and `document.selection`.

Comment: In your case better use the solution without stubs

Comment: Right, I'm not sure why I was saying `document.getSelection` in my question. Once I saw your first bullet I knew that I had misspoken. Also why would stubs be better than spy in this case?

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted In your case `window.getSelection` can be undefined. Hence you cannot use stub for it. Also I did not suggest to replace the stub with a spy. The tools are different. Actually I used spy to check that `window.getSelection().getRangeAt` was called with the argument 0. It is just an additional check. If it is not important for you, you can define `getRangeAt` without the spy.